# Impossible NullPointerException on a play application

Tags: java, playframework, nullpointerexception

I'm getting a really strange NPE exception. This is the offending code:

```
  private static int countRecurse(File file) {
        Preconditions.checkNotNull(file, "file argument");
        int entries = 0;
        for (File entry : file.listFiles()) {    //NPE on this line
            if (entry != null) {
                if (entry.isDirectory())
                    entries += countRecurse(entry);
                else
                    entries++;
            }

        }
        return entries;
    }
```

I get an NPE exception on the commented line. This is the stacktrace I got:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at controllers.StudyPreparation.countRecurse(StudyPreparation.java:103)
        at controllers.StudyPreparation.readDicomFiles(StudyPreparation.java:95)
        at controllers.StudyPreparation.access$100(StudyPreparation.java:30)
        at controllers.StudyPreparation$1.onReady(StudyPreparation.java:77)
        at play.core.j.JavaWebSocket$$anonfun$webSocketWrapper$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(JavaWebSocket.scala:48)
        at play.core.j.JavaWebSocket$$anonfun$webSocketWrapper$1$$anonfun$apply$
```

The code ispart of a Play framework application, but I don't think this could be part of the problem...
Since I already test for file nullity, it can't be null. If something wrong happens inside the listFiles() method, I'll expect to see that on stacktrace.

So what could be the problem?

**EDIT:**

Problem solved checking if file is a directory... the NPE is throwed because file.listFiles() return null.

And even if not documented on javadocs, it return null because the path does not exists.
I didn't check that because on my development machine the procedure is working well, the problem arise only in production server, but is obviouslly related to some other part in code...

Thanks all for your help.

Comment: If `file` is `null` then `Preconditions.checkNotNull(file, "file argument");` will throw a NullPointerException. Are you sure the code being executed is identical to the source code you're looking at? May be worth re-building/cleaning/whatever from your IDE or command line.

Comment: Are you sure `Preconditions.checkNotNull` works as expected ?

Comment: Solution was easy just reading doc of the method/line that was throwing the NPE

Comment: I think the docs are not so accurate... they don't mention that a null is returned also if file does not exists. Well, we can assume that if it does'nt exist, than is not a directory...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From javadoc of file.listFiles()

```
Returns an array of abstract pathnames denoting the files in the directory 
denoted by this abstract pathname. 

If this abstract pathname does not denote a directory, then this method returns 
null. ...
```

So check if `file.isDirectory()` before using `file.listFiles()`.

Comment: So the NPE then happens somewhere in the code produced by the for-each-loop for the iteration, which is not visible directly? That's tricky...

Comment: Problem solved... the NPE is throwed because file.listFiles() return null. But the path is not of a directory, it actually does not exists. I don't understand why listFiles does not throw an appropriate exception...

Answer (score 2):

It could happen that `file.listFiles()` is returning `null` due that File is not a directory.

> If this abstract pathname does not denote a directory, then this method returns null. Otherwise an array of File objects is returned, one for each file or directory in the directory. Pathnames denoting the directory itself and the directory's parent directory are not included in the result. Each resulting abstract pathname is constructed from this abstract pathname using the File(File, String) constructor. Therefore if this pathname is absolute then each resulting pathname is absolute; if this pathname is relative then each resulting pathname will be relative to the same directory.